# Weird package names in snap list?

Tags: snap

Running `snap list` shows the following package names with no information:

```
es
e
ssic
```

[image]

What do these mean ?

Comment: Make your terminal-window a bit wider to see the lines in single rows, e.g. the first line is `Name  Version  Rev  Tracking  Publisher Notes`

Comment: @mook765 is right. Those 'mean' that your terminal window is too narrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid you seem to have reached snapd's minimum supported width, and the text has started wrapping. "es" is simply the last few characters of "Notes" from the line above. Similarly, "ssic" is the last section of the word "classic" and "e" the last character from the word "core". You'll need to make your terminal window a tad wider to view the output without wrapping.